# Exceção System.IO.NotFound para acessar arquivos resx em Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin

Boa Tarde. Estou enfrentando um problema para acessar valores definidos em arquivos resx do código compartilhado no Xamarin Forms. Nenhuma falha ao compilar, mas ao executar recebo yma exceção do tipo File.IO.NotFound, como se o arquivo de resource não existisse dentro do dispositivo móvel (seja no emulador ou em um dispositivo físico.
Para acessar o valor dentro do arquivo de resource, utilizo a seguinte método estático: Resources.Colors.ColorPrimary.
Ações que já foram feitas: Ação de compilação alterar para copiar sempre, Classe de resource alterada para pública. 
ps.: Os arquivos são gerados no diretório bin\debug

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido. Como estava utilizando uma CultureInfo diferente, tive que criar todos os arquivos de resources para a cultura especificada. Como havia separado um arquivo de resource para cada finalidade (Colors, Values e String) tive que criar um arquivo igual para cada cultura.